# Manipulate values of form before sending

Tags: joomla-3.x, form, emails, content-filtering

A customer of mine has a Joomla website with several forms. When submitting these forms an email is sent to my customer with the content. Unfortunately the preset values ("value if empty") are sent as well. Is there a way to remove this values before the mail is sent? The data is processed after the mail and for now these preset values are removed by hand which is rather time consuming. Furthermore I'd like to replace all new lines in the values with spaces before sending the mail.

Comment: What extension is being used?

Comment: Form Maker is used to create the forms

Comment: Another forum extension that I use a lot is RSForm Pro. It has an option for "PHP Scripts" + "PHP Scripts - Pre-Processing" that I use to add my own PHP scripts to retrieve and/or modify data. I don't know Form Maker. Maybe you can ask the developers if they have a similar function?